# UFT Oracle Forms - Default Description Property

Tags: qtp, oracleforms, hp-uft

I am working on autonmation testing an Oracle Forms application with UFT V11.5.

The issue I'm having is that when you add an object in the object repository it adds a "developer name" for the object in the description properties. However, this property is dynamic and changes every time the application is opened. There is, however, a label property that remains static.

Unfortunately, UFT doesn't add the label property by default, meaning that I have to manually delete the developer name property and then add the label. I'd like to make it so that when I add an object to the repository, it uses the label Description property, rather than the developer name - does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UFT (and QTP before it) allows you to change the default object identification settings.  Select 'Tools -> Object Identification' from the main menu.  Select 'Oracle Forms' from the 'Environment' drop-down, then locate the Test Object class you want to tweak.  You can remove 'developer name' from either the mandatory or assistive properties list, and then add the 'label' property in its place.

Note that these settings are machine-specific and will only impact new objects that you learn, not ones already in the object repository.  If you want to "backup" your settings to move to another machine or restore in the future, there is a 'Generate Script' button that will create a VBS file to automatically define the settings.